# Reliable way to determine variable message length when receiving from socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have some Python code for capturing images from a camera and sending them to a C# server.

When sending the messages from the client- I precede the data with the message size so I know how much data to pull from the socket server-side.

It seems to work well most of the time, but occasionally - the message doesn't appear to start with the message size.

I'm not sure why this is happening but I can't figure out how to deal with it.

Python code:

```
while True:
    send_message("SEND_FRAME_DATA_HERE")

def send_message(message):

    message_size = len(message.encode())

    print (f"Message: {message_size} - {message}")

    my_socket.sendall(struct.pack(">L", message_size) + message.encode())
```

C#

```
private const int MESSAGE_CHUNK_SIZE = 4096;
private const int MESSAGE_PREFIX_SIZE = 4;

private void _receiveMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;
    List<byte> messageBuffer = new List<byte>();
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[MESSAGE_CHUNK_SIZE];

    try
    {
        handler.EndReceive(ar);
        messageBuffer.AddRange(state.messageBuffer);

        while (true)
        {
            while (messageBuffer.Count < MESSAGE_PREFIX_SIZE)
            {
                handler.Receive(tempBuffer, 0, MESSAGE_CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
                messageBuffer.AddRange(tempBuffer);
            }

            int messageLength = _getMessageLength(messageBuffer);

            // Occasionally the four bytes determining message length
            // are read from what appears to be mid message
            if (messageLength > 20)
            {
                Console.Write("halp");
            }

            messageBuffer = messageBuffer.Skip(MESSAGE_PREFIX_SIZE).ToList();

            while (messageBuffer.Count < messageLength)
            {
                handler.Receive(tempBuffer, 0, StateObject.messageChunkSize, 0);
                messageBuffer.AddRange(tempBuffer);
            }

            var wholeMessage = messageBuffer.Take(messageLength).ToList();
            var messageString = Encoding.Default.GetString(wholeMessage.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine(messageString);

            messageBuffer = messageBuffer.Skip(messageLength).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private int _getMessageLength(List<byte> message)
{
    byte[] bytes = { message[3], message[2], message[1], message[0] };
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
}
```

The message buffer should look something like this:

[image]

On a good run:

[image]

On a bad run:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The the issue is either you sent wrong size or you didn't pull all the message from previous message.  TCP has a keep alive which is a datagram with zero bytes.  So ignore messages with zero length.  Also your byte count must be the same number of bytes all the time.  So if your size is 0 65535 (2 bytes) don't send one byte as the size.  You receive code must always take two bytes as size.

Comment: The client is just sending the same string over and over so I don't think that could be it.. 

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by byte count must always be the same number? The size should always be the first four bytes of the whole message regardless of the size of the message.. And the message can be variable in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with this code:

```
handler.Receive(tempBuffer, 0, StateObject.messageChunkSize, 0);
messageBuffer.AddRange(tempBuffer);
```

`Socket.Receive()` returns the number of bytes actually read into the `tempBuffer`. You need to save that value, and then use it to copy the correct number of bytes to `messageBuffer`.

```
int bytesRead = handler.Receive(tempBuffer, 0, StateObject.messageChunkSize, 0);
messageBuffer.AddRange(tempBuffer.Take(bytesRead));
```